# Proof: If connected graph G has only one cut-vertex, then every longest path contins the cut vertex.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This is one of exercises from my uni's Discrete math problems. (Non-mandatory) And the job is to either found a counterexample or prove it.

I considered approaching this problem using proof by contradiction – "Connected graph G contains exactly one cut vertex and there exists a longest path such that it doesn't contain the cut vertex."

Let's label the cut vertex $x$ and the longest path $P$.

If $P$ contains one of the neighbours of $x$, then we can make our path longer by one edge.

And I'm somewhat lost as how to proceed in the proof since proving graph-related theorems is one of my weakest links and I'd like to get better.

Is proof by contradiction a bad move to make?

Comment: Here just find a counter example (find a 2-connected non-hamiltonian graph and attach a leaf somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

You will not get better by having others give you the answers. So I will just give you some ideas on what to try.

First of all, when dealing with "prove or disprove" questions, don't just decide on some proof-strategy and get stuck immediately. First get some feeling for the question by fiddling around with examples...

So in this specific instance, what is the simplest graph you can think of, which has a cut vertex? Probably something like $\bullet - \bullet - \bullet$. Does the longest path contain the cut vertex? Find another graph with a cut vertex. Try to find the longest paths and figure out, whether they contain the cut vertex.

Probably this makes you guess that the statement might be true. Now think of what kind of information do you have to your disposal. You know you have a cut vertex, which means that deleting that vertex will make your graph disconnected. What would that mean for a longest path, which is a possible counterexample? Well it would have to be completely in one of the connected components. So if there is a counterexample, it has to be built in such a way that the longest path is completely contained in one of the components (after deleting the cut vertex).

Now you can try to find such a counterexample. Since you only need to ensure a cut vertex and a longest path in one component, it is probably easiest to look for a counterexample, where we have 2 components after deletion and where the component containing the path is fairly large compared to the other one. You might try something like this graph
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
   \bullet \;-\;\bullet \;-\; \bullet \;-\!\! &\bullet& \!\!-\; \bullet \;-\;\bullet\;-\;\bullet\\
   &\mid&\\
   &\circ\\
   &\mid&\\
   &\bullet
\end{array}$$
where $\circ$ denotes the cut-vertex. But note that this is just an Ansatz, since this graph has *many* cut vertices, not just one. Can you "repair" this counterexample? One particular problem is the vertex immediately above the dedicated cut vertex. The problem is that our cut-vertex is connected to the upper component just by means of a single neighbor in this component, making this neighbor another cut vertex. So maybe the graph should look rather like this:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
   \bullet \;-\;\bullet \;-\; \bullet \;-\!\! &\bullet& \!\!-\; \bullet \;-\;\bullet\;-\;\bullet\\
   \diagdown\!\!&\mid&\\
   &\circ\\
   &\mid&\\
   &\bullet
\end{array}$$
But now the longest path is not the longest anymore. Instead of going straight, it would be better for it to pass through the diagonal and then go up again. So maybe the two "upper arms" of our cut-vertex should be spread apart more, so that the distance between the "hands" on the path is larger than 2. You still have to kill the other cut-vertices somehow and I leave that up to you to try to figure out.

If everything fails you can go back to trying to prove the statement. But now you know more! For example you know that your cut-vertex has to send at least two edges into the component of the longest path and you can try to leverage that. And if several strategies (proof by contradiction, proof by induction on the number of vertices or number of edges etc.) fail, you can try to figure out why they failed, to use that knowledge to try to built new counterexamples again.

I hope this answers the question on "how to proceed" in exercises like this. Play pingpong.